# Python - Determine State from Post Code Range

Tags: python, range, postal-code

EXPLANATION: Basically I would like a post code range (6000 - 6997), to determine State "WA" and be listed as "WA" in the State column. So if the post code, for example, is 6100 - the State will be "WA".

There are 4 columns: Customer | Address | State | PostCode

Customer | Address | State | PostCode

Google | 123 Blah Street, Perth | null | 6100

Trying to determine 'State' based on a Post Code range: (6000,6997), should enter "WA" in the column 'State'. Tried several attempts but running into issues.

import re

find_postcode = re.compile(re.escape(x.startswith('6') == 4)
df['State']= df.State.apply(lambda x: find_postcode.sub('WA', str(x)))

OR

PostCode = [range(6000,6997)]
find_postcode = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(PostCode) + r')\b')
df.State.apply(lambda x: find_postcode.sub('WA', str(x)) if x in PostCode else x)

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

Reading through this related [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) will help clarify some things and lead you in the right direction for future decisions. Also the conditional statement you might be looking for is

```
if PostCode >= 6000 and PostCode <= 6997
```